# Does Visual Studio App Center support WPF applications?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-app-center

I'm putting crash analytics into my WPF game to be published on Steam. On **AppCenter.Start(...)** I get this:

> [AppCenter] ASSERT: Cannot use App Center on this target. If you are
>   on Android or iOS or UWP, you must add the NuGet packages in the
>   Android and iOS and UWP projects as well. Other targets are not yet
>   supported.

Can I get App Center into my Desktop WPF applications?

Comment: Probably not: https://github.com/Microsoft/AppCenter-SDK-DotNet/issues/620

Answer (score 0):

It looks like WPF is now supported, at least in preview. See https://github.com/Microsoft/AppCenter-SDK-DotNet/issues/620 and https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter-sdk-dotnet/releases/tag/2.2.1-preview for details.